# python Regex, filtering items from a list

Tags: python, regex

```
laptop/k8s-tv-01.ibm.com/tv-i
laptop/k8s-tv-01.ibm.com/tv-i
laptop/k8s-tv-01.ibm.com/tv-i
laptop/k8s-tv-01.ibm.com/tv-i
laptop/k8s-tv-01.ibm.com/tv-i
laptop/k8s-tv-01.ibm.com/tv-i
laptop/k8s-tv-01.ibm.com/tv-i
laptop/k8s-tv-01.ibm.com/tv-i
laptop/k8s-tv-01.ibm.com/tv-i
laptop/k8s-tv-01.ibm.com/tv-i
laptop/k8s-tv-01.ibm.com/tv-i
```

I want to filter items from a python list.

Format is `laptop/k8s-tv-01.ibm.com/tv-And_some_text` as you can see that there are 2 forward slashes (/).

What I want to achieve is that whatever comes after the 2nd forward slash which starts from

`tv-and_whatever_comes_after`
should appear.

Currently the code I have, it is only filtering till `laptop/k8s-tv-01.ibm.com/tv-i`and whatever comes after is not filtering.

my code

````
```pattern = re.compile(
        r"laptop/k8s-tv-01.ibm.com/tv-[a-zA-Z1-9-]"
    )
    matches = pattern.finditer(stack_loc)
    for match in matches:
        print(match.group())```
````

Comment: Does `tv-and_whatever_comes_after` mean you have a substring right after `tv-` that is underscore-delimited?

Comment: I think all you need is to return the list item that starts with that pattern, like `[x for x in stack_loc if x.startswith('laptop/k8s-tv-01.ibm.com/tv-')]` (no regex required even), see https://ideone.com/dt9jAr

Comment: thank you @WiktorStribiżew your solution has worked :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your regex to this: `(?<=laptop/k8s-tv-01\.ibm\.com/)tv-[a-zA-Z1-9-]`

```
import re
stack = "laptop/k8s-tv-01.ibm.com/tv-and-whatever-comes-after"
pattern = re.compile(
        r"(?<=laptop/k8s-tv-01\.ibm\.com/)tv-[a-zA-Z1-9-]+"
    )
matches = pattern.finditer(stack)
for match in matches:
    print(match.group())    # tv-and-whatever-comes-after
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string = "laptop/k8s-tv-01.ibm.com/tv-i"

match = re.search(r"([^\/]+)$", string)

print(match[0])
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: ok - im new to posting to site - i saw something i could help with so i did. im not really here for the points

i also believe everyone learns differently. i would rather just see code - just my thoughts. feel free to downvote me i dont really care - like i said before i dont care about points.